# Group scheme over a DVR

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-schemes

Let $G$ be a group scheme over a discrete valuation ring $R$, with reductive generic fiber. Would it be the same to require $G$ to have connected generic fiber or to have connected special fiber? Does any of the two conditions imply the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $G$ has connected special fiber, it need not have connected generic fiber:  for example, consider the group scheme $\mu_2$ over $\mathbb Z_2$.  The generic fiber is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, and the special fiber is connected but nonreduced.  However, [this lemma](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/055J) from the Stacks project says that this behavior can't happen without introducing nilpotents.

In the other direction:  Proposition 3.1.12 in [Conrad's notes](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/papers/luminysga3smf.pdf), and its generalization, Theorem 1.2 in [Prasad-Yu](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0405381.pdf), give positive answers under some hypotheses.  I don't know how necessary these hypotheses are.

Note that if you were interested in more general (non-reductive) group schemes, there are interesting examples with connected generic fiber and disconnected special fibers.  For example, Néron models of elliptic curves can have special fibers consisting of several copies of $\mathbb G_m$.

Comment: +1 It's worth mentioning that for affine group schemes the result in Brian's notes is the optimal I was aware of (I had never mentioned Brian's reference to Prasad--Yu) but for proper groups over $R$ things are much better. For example, if $G$ is proper then $G_\eta$ connected implies that $G$ is connected. Indeed, this follows from the more general fact that if $X\to Y$ is proper and surjective with $Y$ integral and normal then $X_\eta$ geometrically connected implies that every fiber of $X$ is geometrically connected

Comment: (e.g. see Corollary 2.23 of this http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~yiouyang/Illusie.pdf). This applies here from the classic fact that if one is connected and has a $k$-point (e.g. as in the case of group schemes) then you're geometrically connected.